# NameError in Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml

I'm getting an error when trying to run code that I wrote. It is code to make an xml file and it reads from a database to get all of the info. The error is being caused by two lines, Document.new and Element.new

If I comment out both of those lines then the code works just fine. I'm not sure why its doing this because those classes should be working just fine.

My code is below:

```
def create_google_file  
  @products = Product.find(:all)
  file = File.new('dir.xml','w')
  doc = Document.new

  root = Element.new "rss"
  root.add_attribute("xmlns:g", "http://base.google.com/ns/1.0")
  root.add_attribute("version", "2.0")

  channel = Element.new "channel"
  root.add_element channel

  title = Element.new "title"
  title.text = "Sample Google Base"
  channel.add_element title

  link = Element.new "link"
  link.text = "http://base.google.com/base/"
  channel.add_element link

  description = Element.new "description"
  description.text = "Information about products"
  channel.add_element description

  @products.each do |y|
    item = channel.add_element("item")

    id = item.add_element("g:id")
    id.text = y.id

    title = item.add_element("title")
    title.text = y.title

    description = item.add_element("description")
    description.text = y.description

    googlecategory = item.add_element("g:google_product_category")
    googlecategory.text = y.googlecategory

    producttype = item.add_element("g:product_type")
    producttype.text = y.producttype

    link = item.add_element("link")
    link.text = y.link

    imglink = item.add_element("g:image_link")
    imglink.text = y.imglink

    condition = item.add_element("condition")
    condition.text = y.condition

    availability = item.add_element("g:availability")
    availability.text = y.availability

    price = item.add_element("g:price")
    price.text = y.price "USD"

    gtin = item.add_element("g:gtin")
    gtin.text = y.gtin

    brand = item.add_element("g:brand")
    brand.text = y.brand

    mpn = item.add_element("g:mpn")
    mpn.text = y.mpn

    expirationdate = item.add_element("g:expiration_date")
    expirationdate.text = y.salepricedate
  end   

  doc.add_element root

  file.puts doc
  file.close
  end
```

The error I'm getting is:
NameError in ProductsController#create_google_file

uninitialized constant ProductsController::Element

and

NameError in ProductsController#create_google_file

uninitialized constant ProductsController::Document

Comment: Where Document and Element are defined? Are you sure that rails loads files with this classes?

Comment: I believe it does because I was following along with a tutorial that I found at http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/tutorials/x-rubyonrailsxml/section4.html and it seems to say that rails comes with those classes loaded

Comment: Well, but in that tutorial they use different naming `REXML::Document`, and you type just `Document`. Also you should require this lib before usage, yes it is in default lib, but it is not loaded by default, write at the top of controller file `require "rexml/document"`

Comment: I changed it and added the require part for document and element but now I'm getting an error message saying that it can't load such file -- element

Comment: You should not require element seperately, it is required by rexml/document. You should probably read official docs http://www.germane-software.com/software/rexml/

Comment: Well I thought so too but if I don't require element then it just gives me a name error for element

Comment: Did you switch to using REXML::Element as well?

Comment: Yes I did and I still got the same message. What else could be causing this problem? I'm not seeing anyone else with this issue anywhere