# NameError in Controller uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Got this error:

```
Started POST "/webhook" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-18 11:50:26 +0300
Processing by Stripe::WebhooksController#webhook as XML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"evt_14osuo2XLHInsdy70EAY7Iuf", "created"=>1413622222, "livemode"=>false, ...}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 963ms

NameError (uninitialized constant Stripe::WebhooksController::Account):
  app/controllers/stripe/webhooks_controller.rb:10:in `webhook'
```

within controller

```
class Stripe::WebhooksController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery :except => [:webhook]

  def webhook
    @event = Stripe::Event.retrieve(params[:id])
    @object = @event.data.object
    if @object.object == 'customer'
      @account = Account.find(@object.id)
    else
      @account = Account.find(@object.customer)
    end
    @subscription = @account.subscription
    render nothing: true
  end
end
```

Account is a class and I want to get an object out of this class, why error says `Stripe::WebhooksController::Account`, couldn't find any explanation why this behave like this. How can I fix this? 
Thank you.

p.s. found a similar [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13976119/nameerror-in-controller) but no answer to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's more usual not to namespace your application controller under `Stripe`

It would be better to do...

```
class WebhooksController < ApplicationController
```

If you insist on the namespace, then you'll have to be explicit that `Account` is outside the namespace and accessed from root.

```
@account = ::Account.find(@object.id)
```

Comment: Thank you very much mister, learned something new. Wondering why it worked a few days already and failed only a few hours ago. Anyway, thank you for your help.

Comment: Well, yes, I wonder that myself sometimes. :)  I don't honestly understand how the "default" namespace is sometimes different and when I had the similar problem it got a little unpredictable. Generally, and except when versioning APIs, I avoid namespacing my classes and it makes my life easer.

Comment: @magnum2002, I have also seen all sorts of strange things with namespacing too, I am coming to the opinion unless you have a really deep knowledge of how it works, you are best to avoid it.